# How to calculate area of polygon that does not overlap with other polygons in R?

Tags: r, gis, polygon

I have a SpatialPoints object with the coordinates for several points of interest.
I also have several shapefiles (polygons) with information about the presence of slums. The polygons with info about slums in each of these shapefiles can overlap (they provide somewhat the same information about the presence of slums, but come from different sources).

For each of the points in my SpatialPoints object, I have used the function spCircle to create a circular polygon around each point. What I need to do next is to check what percentage of the area of the circular polygon contains slums. If **any** of the shapefiles indicates that the slum is present, I will consider that there is a slum in the area.

I have created the following image to help explain my issue. The circles represent the polygon around a single point. For this single point, each of the four shapefiles indicates that the slum is present in somewhat different areas (sometimes they overlap, and sometimes they do not). I want to be able to find the red area (where none of the shapefiles indicate the presence of the slum, and then calculate the percentage of the circle that has slums.

[image]

The following code is an attempt to do that:

```
# Create data with coordinates

lat = c(-22.868879628748203,-22.88511,-22.82166,-22.89692,-22.67945)
long = c(-43.237195000177564,-43.34278,-43.04717,-43.35168,-43.59667)

data_points = cbind.data.frame(lat,long)

coordinates(data_points) = c("lat","long")
proj4string(data_points) = CRS("+init=epsg:4326") 

# Transform projection of points to UTM

utmStr <- "+proj=utm +zone=%d +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80"
crs <- CRS(sprintf(utmStr, 23))
data_points = spTransform(data_points, crs)


# Create a list with circular polygons around each point (radius = 2000 meters)

circular_grid = list()

for (i in 1:length(data_points)){
  
  spc = spCircle(radius = 2000, centerPoint = c(x=as.numeric(data_points@coords[i,1]), y=as.numeric(data_points@coords[i,2])), spID=i,
                 spUnits = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=23 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"))
  circular_grid[[i]] = spc
}


# For each circle, check the percentage that overlaps with several different shapefiles:

# I first use gUnion to merge all the shapefiles with info about slums together

allShapes = gUnion(shape1,shape2)
allShapes = gUnion(allShapes, shape3)
allShapes = gUnion(allShapes, shape4)
allShapes = gUnion(allShapes, shape5)
allShapes = gUnion(allShapes, shape6)
allShapes = as(allShapes, "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")

allShapes = spTransform(allShapes, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=23 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"))

# I am unable to reproduce the object "allShapes" (I do not know how),
# but this is its information

# class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
# features    : 1 
# extent      : 633347.1, 724692.1, -2547787, -2513212  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# crs         : +proj=utm +zone=23 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs 
# variables   : 1
# names       : dummy 
# value       :     0

# Next, to get the intersection, I tried the following:

intersection_circle_shape = list()

for (i in 1:length(circular_grid)){
  
  circle = circular_grid[[i]][["spCircle"]]
  
  inter = intersect(circle, allShapes)
  
  intersection_circle_shape[[i]] = inter
  
}


# The list "intersection_circle_shape" is empty because the command
# "intersect" says that there is no intersection, but I know there is.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: it would be helpful if you could paste your code and show us your data frame at the start. I think many of us could provide you with a solution afterwards.